# Postgresql order model with relationship boolean field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Morning

I have no idea how make pg order by relation boolean field. True is top.

Here is my solution but it's too heavy cos using **sort_by**. Could it be override with **order**?

```
Solution.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).sort_by{|a| a.user.admin? ||   a.user.moderator? ? 1: 0}
```

Where

```
class Solution < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Voteable, Classifiable, Archiveable, GeoTaggable
  include WithAssets, WithStats, WithEvents

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Scheme

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ...
    admin boolean DEFAULT false,
    moderator boolean
);

CREATE TABLE solutions (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    user_id integer,
    body text,
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

order working on database. you should add more information about you database schema or use current solution.